# ¿Cómo puedo mandar los valores de un input-date al backend de una forma correcta?

Tags: jquery

Se me presentó el siguiente problema, deseo mandar mediante un formulario en un campo especifico donde se elige la fecha de nacimiento, la situación es que no esta realizando el guardado correctamente.

```html
<div class="input-group col-xs-4">
  <div class="input-group-addon">
    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
  </div>
  <input type="date" id="fechaNacimiento" name="fechaNacimiento" class="form-control" data-inputmask="'alias': 'dd/mm/yyyy'" data-mask="">
</div>
```

Y este es el script con el que quiero mandar con un método AJAX y recuperando con `jquery` la fecha que se eligió para guardar en la BD.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#btn-save-locutor', function() {
  loadMask('content-form-locutor');
  $.ajax({
    url: '{{ route('
    locutor.save ') }}',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      id: $("#id").val(),
      primerApellido: $('#primerApellido').val(),
      segundoApellido: $('#segundoApellido').val(),
      nombres: $('#nombres').val(),
      procedencia: $('#procedencia_seleccionada').val(),
      genero: $('#genero_seleccionada').val(),
      fechaNacimiento: ('fechaNacimiento').val()
    },
    success: function(response) {
      location.reload(); // recarga la pagina
    }
  });
});
```

No se si estoy guardando correctamente el campo `fachaNacimiento` el facha elegida en input-date.

Comment: ¿El resto de parámetros llegan bien a la función ajax? ``fechaNacimiento`` ¿cómo llega? ¿vacío? Imagino que el campo ya no te llega bien antes de pasar al backend

Comment: A `fechaNacimiento` le falta el selector por id `#`. Tendría que ser `('#fechaNacimiento').val()`

Comment: Además también le falta el simbolo '$' del principio: $('#fechaNacimiento').val()

Comment: Cierto. No me había dado cuenta de ese detalle :)

Comment: muchas gracias a todos.... ya me corrio.... se los agradezco Coders!!!